# Why ERROR_INVALID_HOOK_HANDLE happen

Tags: c#

> Error Name: ERROR_INVALID_HOOK_HANDLE
>
> Error Code: 1404 (0x57C)
>
> Description: Invalid hook handle.

My Question is:

1) Does anybody know when above system error code happen?

2) Can `UnhookWindowsHookEx()` function cause above system code?

I have been searching by Googling. But, I could not found any sure answer.
Please, anybody help me.

Actually, I am developing an application that make remote connection to other machine.
That application also monitor what user doing on the remote machine.

To monitor user's action, I installed custom hook procedure for WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL hooks at the time of connecting to remote machine. I installed the hook procedure using SetWindowsHookEx() method.

The following code include custom hook procedure definition for WH_KEYBOARD_LL and installing that hook procedure to hook chains of WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook.

```
// custom keyboard hook procedure
private static int KeyboardHookProc(int nCode, Int32 wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        //indicates if any of underlaing events set e.Handled flag
        bool handled = false;

        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            //read structure KeyboardHookStruct at lParam
            KeyboardHookStruct MyKeyboardHookStruct = (KeyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KeyboardHookStruct));
            //raise KeyDown
            if (s_KeyDown != null && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN))
            {
                Keys keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.VirtualKeyCode;
                KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
                s_KeyDown.Invoke(null, e);
                handled = e.Handled;
            }

            // raise KeyPress
            if (s_KeyPress != null && wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                bool isDownShift = ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x80) == 0x80 ? true : false);
                bool isDownCapslock = (GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) != 0 ? true : false);

                byte[] keyState = new byte[256];
                GetKeyboardState(keyState);
                byte[] inBuffer = new byte[2];
                if (ToAscii(MyKeyboardHookStruct.VirtualKeyCode,
                          MyKeyboardHookStruct.ScanCode,
                          keyState,
                          inBuffer,
                          MyKeyboardHookStruct.Flags) == 1)
                {
                    char key = (char)inBuffer[0];
                    if ((isDownCapslock ^ isDownShift) && Char.IsLetter(key)) key = Char.ToUpper(key);
                    KeyPressEventArgs e = new KeyPressEventArgs(key);
                    s_KeyPress.Invoke(null, e);
                    handled = handled || e.Handled;
                }
            }

            // raise KeyUp
            if (s_KeyUp != null && (wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP))
            {
                Keys keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.VirtualKeyCode;
                KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);
                s_KeyUp.Invoke(null, e);
                handled = handled || e.Handled;
            }

        }

        //if event handled in application do not handoff to other listeners
        if (handled)
            return -1;

        //forward to other application
        return CallNextHookEx(s_KeyboardHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

// installing keyboard hook procedure
private static void EnsureSubscribedToGlobalKeyboardEvents()
    {
        // install Keyboard hook only if it is not installed and must be installed
        if (s_KeyboardHookHandle == 0)
        {
            //See comment of this field. To avoid GC to clean it up.
            s_KeyboardDelegate = KeyboardHookProc;
            //install hook
            s_KeyboardHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
                s_KeyboardDelegate,
                Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                0);
            //If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
            if (s_KeyboardHookHandle == 0)
            {
                //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                //do cleanup

                //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

The following code include custom hook procedure definition for WH_MOUSE_LL and installing that hook procedure to hook chains of WH_MOUSE_LL hook.

```
// custom mouse hook procedure
private static int MouseHookProc(int nCode, int wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            //Marshall the data from callback.
            MouseLLHookStruct mouseHookStruct = (MouseLLHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MouseLLHookStruct));

            //detect button clicked
            MouseButtons button = MouseButtons.None;
            short mouseDelta = 0;
            int clickCount = 0;
            bool mouseDown = false;
            bool mouseUp = false;

            switch (wParam)
            {
                case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                    mouseDown = true;
                    button = MouseButtons.Left;
                    clickCount = 1;
                    break;
                case WM_LBUTTONUP:
                    mouseUp = true;
                    button = MouseButtons.Left;
                    clickCount = 1;
                    break;
                case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK: 
                    button = MouseButtons.Left;
                    clickCount = 2;
                    break;
                case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
                    mouseDown = true;
                    button = MouseButtons.Right;
                    clickCount = 1;
                    break;
                case WM_RBUTTONUP:
                    mouseUp = true;
                    button = MouseButtons.Right;
                    clickCount = 1;
                    break;
                case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK: 
                    button = MouseButtons.Right;
                    clickCount = 2;
                    break;
                case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
                    //If the message is WM_MOUSEWHEEL, the high-order word of MouseData member is the wheel delta. 
                    //One wheel click is defined as WHEEL_DELTA, which is 120. 
                    //(value >> 16) & 0xffff; retrieves the high-order word from the given 32-bit value
                    mouseDelta = (short)((mouseHookStruct.MouseData >> 16) & 0xffff);

                //TODO: X BUTTONS (I havent them so was unable to test)
                    //If the message is WM_XBUTTONDOWN, WM_XBUTTONUP, WM_XBUTTONDBLCLK, WM_NCXBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCXBUTTONUP, 
                    //or WM_NCXBUTTONDBLCLK, the high-order word specifies which X button was pressed or released, 
                    //and the low-order word is reserved. This value can be one or more of the following values. 
                    //Otherwise, MouseData is not used. 
                    break;
            }

            //generate event 
            MouseEventExtArgs e = new MouseEventExtArgs(
                                               button,
                                               clickCount,
                                               mouseHookStruct.Point.X,
                                               mouseHookStruct.Point.Y,
                                               mouseDelta);

            //Mouse up
            if (s_MouseUp!=null && mouseUp)
            {
                s_MouseUp.Invoke(null, e);
            }

            //Mouse down
            if (s_MouseDown != null && mouseDown)
            {
                s_MouseDown.Invoke(null, e);
            }

            //If someone listens to click and a click is heppened
            if (s_MouseClick != null && clickCount>0)
            {
                s_MouseClick.Invoke(null, e);
            }

            //If someone listens to click and a click is heppened
            if (s_MouseClickExt != null && clickCount > 0)
            {
                s_MouseClickExt.Invoke(null, e);
            }

            //If someone listens to double click and a click is heppened
            if (s_MouseDoubleClick != null && clickCount == 2)
            {
                s_MouseDoubleClick.Invoke(null, e);
            }

            //Wheel was moved
            if (s_MouseWheel!=null && mouseDelta!=0)
            {
                s_MouseWheel.Invoke(null, e);
            }

            //If someone listens to move and there was a change in coordinates raise move event
            if ((s_MouseMove!=null || s_MouseMoveExt!=null) && (m_OldX != mouseHookStruct.Point.X || m_OldY != mouseHookStruct.Point.Y))
            {
                m_OldX = mouseHookStruct.Point.X;
                m_OldY = mouseHookStruct.Point.Y;
                if (s_MouseMove != null)
                {
                    s_MouseMove.Invoke(null, e);
                }

                if (s_MouseMoveExt != null)
                {
                    s_MouseMoveExt.Invoke(null, e);
                }
            }

            if (e.Handled)
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        //call next hook
        return CallNextHookEx(s_MouseHookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

// installing mouse hook procedure
private static void EnsureSubscribedToGlobalMouseEvents()
    {
        // install Mouse hook only if it is not installed and must be installed
        if (s_MouseHookHandle == 0)
        {
            //See comment of this field. To avoid GC to clean it up.
            s_MouseDelegate = MouseHookProc;
            //install hook
            s_MouseHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(
                WH_MOUSE_LL,
                s_MouseDelegate,
                Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]),
                0);
            //If SetWindowsHookEx fails.
            if (s_MouseHookHandle == 0)
            {
                //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                //do cleanup

                //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

When user disconnect from the target server, I have to uninstall these hook procedures again.

The following are the codes for uninstalling hook procedures for WH_KEYBOARD_LL and WH_MOUSE_LL hooks.

```
// uninstalling custom mouse hook procedure
private static void ForceUnsunscribeFromGlobalMouseEvents()
    {
        if (s_MouseHookHandle != 0)
        {
            //uninstall hook
            int result = UnhookWindowsHookEx(s_MouseHookHandle);
            //reset invalid handle
            s_MouseHookHandle = 0;
            //Free up for GC
            s_MouseDelegate = null;
            //if failed and exception must be thrown
            if (result == 0)
            {
                //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }
        }
    }

//uninstalling custom keyboard hook procedure
private static void ForceUnsunscribeFromGlobalKeyboardEvents()
    {
        if (s_KeyboardHookHandle != 0)
        {
            //uninstall hook
            int result = UnhookWindowsHookEx(s_KeyboardHookHandle);
            //reset invalid handle
            s_KeyboardHookHandle = 0;
            //Free up for GC
            s_KeyboardDelegate = null;
            //if failed and exception must be thrown
            if (result == 0)
            {
                //Returns the error code returned by the last unmanaged function called using platform invoke that has the DllImportAttribute.SetLastError flag set. 
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                //Initializes and throws a new instance of the Win32Exception class with the specified error. 
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I uninstalling the hook procedures, I got ERROR_INVALID_HOOK_HANDLE error returned by Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() for sometimes. But not always.
I don't really have any ideas with this. So, I tried to ask about ERROR_INVALID_HOOK_HANDLE error in this post.

Comment: what is the context? what are you trying to do? show us some code.

Comment: Where you are using it? Are you manipulating with the registry?
Share some more information to get better answer..

Comment: A handle is an IntPtr, not an int.  This code is thus likely to fail on a 64-bit operating system.  Using Marshal.GetHINSTANCE() is no longer reliable on .NET 4.0 and up.  Only use this code if you target .NET 3.5 and force the program to run in 32-bit mode.

Comment: So, for the handler it should be IntPtr rather than int. For Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(), what should i use instead of this. My application is meant to be run on .NET 3.5 and window server 2008 r2 64-bit